# reverse a linkedlist recursively

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

**my linkedlist reverse function gives the correct result. but i am

confused.**

```
linked list= 12->5->4->3

as per my reverse function the result should be
4->5->12

but fortunately it produces the correct reversed list
3->4->5->12.

pls help me to understand what happening 




//head_ref  global variable



struct n* reverse(struct n *head){

    struct n *pre,*cur;  //temp variable for first and second node

    if(head->next==NULL){
        head_ref = head;   // head_ref global variable initialized with head pointer
        return;
     }
    pre = head;
    cur = head->next;
    reverse(cur);

    cur->next = pre ;
    pre->next = NULL;

 }
```

first call
   pre = 12
          cur = 5
      second call 
          pre = 5
          cur = 4
      3rd call
          pre = 4
          cur = 3

```
   3->next = NULL //base condition fullfilled
   so it will exit ( 3rd call )

   reverse will start from 
   second call
      pre = 5
      cur = 4
```

my reversed  linked list should be  4->5->12

but it produces 3->4->5->12 (correct reversed linked list)

why it gives the correct result. pls explain????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us start with linked list  `12->5->4->3`.
When your main (or other calling function) calls the reverse function, head has the data 12. Following is the stack created after the forth call to the reverse function.

```
                 |                                           |
                 |___________________________________________|     gonna be
                 |__*head=3 *head->next=NULL__head_ref=3_____| => popped out
                 |__*head=4 pre=4 curr=3_____________________|   
                 |__*head=5 pre=5 cur=4______________________|
     main calls=>|__*head=12_pre=12 cur=5____________________|
```

As you said, you are already clear with the above figure. When we have head->next = NULL, the top-most entry in the stack gets popped out and the one with *head=4, pre=4 and curr=3 becomes the topmost entry in the stack. Then curr->prev evaluates to 
3->next=4 and 4->next->NULL.

```
                 |                                                      |
                 |                                                      |
    popped out=> |______________________________________________________|
                 |__*head=4 pre=4 curr=3__(3->next)=4__(4->next)=NULL___|
                 |__*head=5 pre=5 cur=4_________________________________|
                 |__*head=12_pre=12 cur=5_______________________________|
```

Then entry with *head=4 pre=4 curr=3__(3->next)=4__(4->next)=NULL pops out and the same thing happens.

```
                 |                                                      |
                 |                                                      |
                 |                                                      |
    popped out=> |______________________________________________________|
                 |__*head=5 pre=5 cur=4____(4->next)=5___(5->next=NULL)_|
                 |__*head=12_pre=12 cur=5_______________________________|
```

In the remaining one entry you can see 12->next becomes NULL, so 12 now becomes the tail of the linked list.

```
                 |                                                      |
                 |                                                      |
                 |                                                      |
                 |                                                      |
    popped out=> |______________________________________________________|
                 |__*head=12_pre=12 cur=5__(5->next)=12_(12->next)=NULL_| 


                 |                                                      |
                 |                                                      |
                 |                                                      |
                 |                                                      |
                 |                                                      |
    popped out=> |______________________________________________________|
```

Stack becomes empty and your final linked list has 3 as the head and 12 as the tail:`3->4->5->12`

Answer (score 2):

> 3->next = NULL //base condition fullfilled    so it will exit ( 3rd
>   call )
>
> reverse will start from     second call
>         pre = 5
>         cur = 4

No reverse start from here

> call pre = 4 cur = 3

you call reverse(3) which do nothing,
and you execute lines

```
cur->next = pre ;
pre->next = NULL;
```

where cur=3 and pre = 4, so you got **3->4**

Comment: each recursive call will create separate scope. so when reverse(3) get called it is returned. so the scope of reverse(3) will be finished. and scope of reverse(4)   will come into effect. at that time cur value was 4.

Comment: @raton Yes at each call of reverse you have new scope, but you forget that scope was restored after `reverse(cur);` You have `pre = 4; cur = 3; reverse(3); 3->next = 4; 4->next = NULL;` what is not clear?